# Как поставить свою тему на страницу магазина woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я почти полностью интегрировал верстку на WP и мне осталось подключить WC. Я это сделал. И возник вопрос. Всю страницу магазина нужно будет менять самому или же можно как-то хоть немного интегрировать свою тему? Мой header и footer там стоит, но header перекрывается header WC и я не знаю, как это решить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет кастомизировать страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно интегрировать, но для этого нужно будет поработать с шаблонами WooCommerce. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ более подробно описано в пунтке https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1

Если все равно не совсем понятно что делать, на YouTube можно найти плейлист с видео на русском, где все более подробно [описывается](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRxOu5XZh2s&list=PLzFj4L-LMRzsaNrS00le_wWsZed7PTu2F)

Comment: Благодарю! Решил проблемы свои.